# Swift core data saving to multiple entity's

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

In my view I have UITextfields for all except note which is a UITextView.  When I hit save it dose save all the data but dose not link the note to the Teas entity.

```
 @IBAction func addTea(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Teas", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var newItem = dataModel(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newItem.teaname = teaName.text
    newItem.teatype = teaType.text
    newItem.amount = qty.text
    newItem.temp = temp.text
    newItem.time = time.text
    let en1 = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Notes", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let newNote = dataNote(entity: en1!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newNote.note = note.text


    println(note.text)
    context.save(nil)

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

dataModel.swift

```
@objc(dataModel)
class dataModel: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var amount: String
@NSManaged var teaname: String
@NSManaged var teatype: String
@NSManaged var temp: String
@NSManaged var time: String
@NSManaged var notes: dataNote

}
```

notes.swift

```
@objc(dataNote)
class dataNote: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var note: String
@NSManaged var teas: dataModel

}
```

I think after looking at a lot of other examples I need some thing like this.

```
 @IBAction func addTea(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Teas", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var newItem = dataModel(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newItem.teaname = teaName.text
    newItem.teatype = teaType.text
    newItem.amount = qty.text
    newItem.temp = temp.text
    newItem.time = time.text
    newItem.notesRel = noteAdd.text
```

But I get 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'dataNote'

Comment: The warning you are reporting often is due to the lack of `@objc()` mark for your data class. Anyway your model isn't clear to me: it appears that `notes` is not a to many relation. `notes` can actually be just one note.

Comment: The note should only be linked to one object in the dataModel.